# Start a new line after every comma

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, newline

i am fetching currencies from the internet then trying to format them so every currency is on a new line, hoping someone could help me out

hoping to get an output something like this:

{

"AED" : "united Arab Emirates Dirham",

"AFN" : "Afghan Afghani",

...........

"ZWL" : "Zimbabwean Dollar"

}

My Code is as follows:

```
import json
import urllib.request
f = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~mbbssvs4/python/currencies.json')
charset = f.info().get_param('charset', 'utf8')
data = f.read()
decoded = json.loads(data.decode(charset))
print(decoded)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `json.dumps`:

```py
import json
j = json.loads("""{
"AED" : "united Arab Emirates Dirham",
"AFN" : "Afghan Afghani",
"ZWL" : "Zimbabwean Dollar"
}""")
print json.dumps(j, indent=4)
```

Output:

```
{
    "AFN": "Afghan Afghani", 
    "ZWL": "Zimbabwean Dollar", 
    "AED": "united Arab Emirates Dirham"
}
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html